# Why does accuracy of Naive Bayes model lower than Neural Network model too much?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, naivebayes

I have a dataset with >16k vectors (21 dimensions).

I use 80% for training and 20% for testing.

I implement Neural Network and Naive Bayes with above dataset.

Get dataset and split it

```py
data_set = np.loadtxt("./data/_vector21.csv", delimiter=",")

inp_vec = data_set[:, 1:22]
out_vec = data_set[:, 22:]

# Split dataset into training set and test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inp_vec, out_vec, test_size=0.2)  # 80% training and 20% test
```

Neural Network

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(21, 100, 100, 6), max_iter=1000)
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = mlp.predict(X_test)
print("\nAccuracy: %.2f%%\n" % (accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)*100))

# Accuracy: 61.26%
```

Naive Bayes

```py
# Create a Gaussian Classifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
model = GaussianNB()

# Train the model using the training sets
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print("\nAccuracy: %.3f%%" % (metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100))

#Accuracy: 34.050%
```

I expect the output of Neural Network model and Naive Bayes model closer.

Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong and how can fix that?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, that is the only issue.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, can you explain it for me?

Comment: What's the basis of your expectations? Why do you think NB and MLP will perform similar? If you want clarification on that, then StackOverflow is not the appropriate site for this. Try [Cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @VivekKumar, I just a newbie in machine learning and I try to implement MLP and NB because, in some documents, they performed quite well, so I hope that when I try with the same dataset, the results at least closer than what I have above.